# How to upload multipart form data inside a dictionary?

Tags: swift, alamofire

I am trying to upload a video to my rails API backend using Swift. To upload this I use Alamofire. The only problem is that the rails api is expecting this: `{"video":{"clip": (form data)}}`. The problem that I am having is storing the multipart form data is that it doesn't seem I can store it inside the second dictionary. I have tried params for my video, but it doesn't seem to work. Here is some of my code if it helps:

**The Alamofire Request**

```
AF.upload(
            multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in
                for (_, _) in params {
                    multipartFormData.append(self.videoURL, withName: "clip" , fileName: "clip.mp4", mimeType: "video/mp4")
                }
                multipartFormData.append("\(Id)".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8, allowLossyConversion: false)!, withName :"Id")
        },
            to: "http://10.0.0.2:3000/api/v1/videouploads.json", method: .post, headers: headers)
            .response { resp in
                print(resp)


        }
```

**What the server expects (pretty printed)**

```
        {
            "video": {
                "clip": (multipartformdata)
            }
            "id": (user id)
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```swift
multipartFormData.append(
    self.videoURL, 
    withName: "video[clip]", // this is location in form' struct
    fileName: "clip.mp4", 
    mimeType: "video/mp4"
)
```